# Is it correct/idiomatic to say "got informed there?"

Tags: phrases, word-usage

I thought the phrase was common/idiomatic. So I was surprised when I got [0](https://www.google.com.tw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1ASUT_enTW470TW470&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22got%20informed%20there%22&tbm=bks) results on Google Books.

> The school was filled with gossip. So Anna probably got informed there (about someone's whereabouts).

Comment: The school was full of gossip. So Anna was probably told there.

Comment: ...so Anna probably heard it there.

Comment: ...so Anna probably learnt (about) it there.

Comment: ... so Anna probably *found out* there.

Comment: so Anna probably *picked up the information* there.

Comment: There isn't anything strictly wrong with the way it is phrased, it is grammatical, but just sounds clumsy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a phrase. But there's no reason why the passive verbal phrase *got informed* shouldn't be followed by the deictic adverb *there*.